# FileOpener in ionic2 native for android

Tags: android, ionic2, fileopener2

Im using FileOpener in ionic2 native

Doc [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/fileopener/).

this is my code :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { FileOpener } from 'ionic-native';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-installHelper',
  templateUrl: 'installHelper.html'
})
export class InstallHelper {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public fo: FileOpener) {
        fo.open('/assets/app.apk', 'application/vnd.android.package-archive');
  }

}
```

but it gives an error says : `Property 'open' does not exist on type 'FileOpener'.`

I want to open an apk file from my App.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With native components, you don't assign it to the constructor.

So your code should look like:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { FileOpener } from 'ionic-native';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-installHelper',
  templateUrl: 'installHelper.html'
})
export class InstallHelper {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
        FileOpener.open('/assets/app.apk', 'application/vnd.android.package-archive',
        { 
            error : (e)=> {console.log('Error status: ' + e.status + ' - Error message: ' + e.message);},
            success : ()=> {console.log('file opened successfully');}
        });
  }

}
```

Comment: Ooh Thank you so much... I'll try it.

Comment: Opss I got this error : 

1     038429   error    EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): [object Object]
2     038438   error    ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
3     038443   error    Error: Uncaught (in promise): [object Object]
    at s (http://192.168.1.37:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:8568)
    at http://192.168.1.37:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:8318
    at Object.cordova.callbackFromNative (http://192.168.1.37:8100/cordova.js:295:52)

Comment: at processMessage (http://192.168.1.37:8100/cordova.js:1119:17)
    at processMessages (http://192.168.1.37:8100/cordova.js:1142:9)
    at t.invoke (http://192.168.1.37:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:13422)
    at Object.inner.inner.fork.onInvoke (http://192.168.1.37:8100/build/main.js:3:25181)
    at t.invoke (http://192.168.1.37:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:13373)
    at e.run (http://192.168.1.37:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:10809)
    at http://192.168.1.37:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:8911

Comment: Thats a different error. It means that their is something wrong with the code, but you don't have an error call back. I will update the answer with a callback

Comment: I have edited the answer to include the error response. Your error will persist, but you will have more information for debug

Comment: thanks for your effort ... yeah that one now gives a callback you're right ...

and now the callback said File Not Found ... and after I made researches on google I didn't find how to open a file from within the /assets folder of the app it self and not from file system folder like /Download or anyting.

is that even possible ? here is the project hierarchy :  

AppFolder
-www
-src
--- assets
-------app.apk
---pages
------installHelper
----------installHelper.ts
----------installHelper.htm
----------installHelper.scss
--- app
--- theme
.
.
.
-platforms
-hooks
.
.
.

Comment: Since that is a different problem, could you mark this answer as accepted and raise another question and I'll try help you there

Comment: but quickly, try without the first '/' so .. FileOpener.open('assets/app.apk', '...

Comment: I did it and it gives : 

1     678771   log      status : 9
2     678772   log      error : File not found

Comment: Ok, accept this answer for your original issue and make a new question

Comment: Done Thank you here is the new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40891028/open-a-file-within-the-app-folder-with-fileopener-ionic2